# ASP.NET C# No rows in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView (with one radio button) named `DGV_Pay1` with a DataSet as DataSource.

The definition of GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="DGV_Pay1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                           AllowPaging="false" EnableViewState="false" >
                          <Columns>
                              <asp:TemplateField>
                                  <ItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:RadioButton ID="radioPay1" runat="server" />
                                      <asp:HiddenField ID="radioPay1Value" runat="server" Value='<% Eval("ID") %>' />
                                  </ItemTemplate>
                              </asp:TemplateField>
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="NOME" HeaderText="Fee name" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="TOTALE" HeaderText="Total" />
                              <asp:BoundField DataField="VALIDA_AL" HeaderText="Expiry date" />
                          </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The method that bind the DataSet:

```
protected void Pay1_On(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NascondiPanel();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            ds = SQLManager.GetTariffeEvento(ev.id, 1);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            panelGeneral.Visible = false;
            panelError.Visible = true;
            lbErrore.Text = ex.Message;
            return;
        }

        DGV_Pay1.DataSource = ds;
        DGV_Pay1.DataBind();
        PanelPay1.Visible = true;

    }
```

After the execution I have one row in the GridView.
But when I select the radio button and press the submit button, the following method does not detect any rows...

```
protected void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        [...]

        int tariffa = -100;
        if(Pay1.Checked) //Yes, it's checked! It's a radio out the GridView...
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < DGV_Pay1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                [...]
            }


        }

      [...]

    }
```

Any ideas?
Thanks...

Comment: with _enableviewstate = false_ you need to rebind at each postback

Comment: @Steve It works. Thanks. :)

Comment: If you always only dealing with 1 row, Gridview is probably the wrong tool for the job here.